# Swift - UISwitch as selector between two values?

Tags: swift, uiswitch

I want as an option in an app I'm building to offer the user to select between seeing temperatures in Celsius (C) or Fahrenheit (F). This option will be shown within a tableview controller.

My initial thought was to use an UISwitch for this but this would require adding labels left and right of the UISwitch and linking the on/off to either C or F.

Is there a better way or will I need a custom control for this?

Thanks!

Kostas

Comment: You could use a `UISegmentedControl` instead, but considering that this is something that the user is not going to change often it may be better to place it in a 'settings' screen of some sort (if you're not doing it alreay of course... something like in the stock weather app in iOS)

Comment: Thanks @Alladinian! Will do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`UISegmentedControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html) for that:

It would look like that:

[image]

As you see you can make multiple items so if there is another option to choose, you can easily add it.